# PostSharp + Microsoft.Bcl.Async on .net 4.0

Tags: c#, postsharp

I'm creating a .net 4.0 application which uses `PostSharp` 2.1 for AOP. 
Now that [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) is stable, I'd like to use `async` in this application.

However, when doing so, I'm running into the following `PostSharp` issue:

```
PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. [Public key mismatch] 
============ PostSharp Assembly Loading Log =================== 
LOG: Finding the assembly with binding identity 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. 
LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' because this file was explicitly added to the search path. 
LOG: File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' has identity 'mscorlib, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089, processorarchitecture=msil'. 
LOG: File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' does not match the reference.
```

This only happens when the assembly to be compiled references `System.ServiceModel` and contains the following code:

```
new FaultContractAttribute(typeof(SomeType));
```

I'm guessing that this has something to do with the `[__DynamicallyInvokable]` attribute on the `System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute` `ctor`, which says:

```
"Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries".
```

Has anybody ran into the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft.BCL is not supported yet by PostSharp (we are at v3.0.38 at the time of writing). You can vote for the feature here: https://postsharp.uservoice.com/forums/4949-general/suggestions/4225929-support-for-microsoft-bcl